# How can I video record with expo gl and camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, webgl

Any help on how to record video with expo gl view.

I have successfully applied face filters using Expo face detection but I want to record video with the filters on. So I saw somewhere that I should set up a scene with gl view for that.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?